# iOS webview load another url with Safari

Tags: ios, uiwebview

I am making an app for iOS, use UIwebview to load my website in the app. I want all links (besides my website) open in Safari. Read many articles and tried many different suggestion still can't make it.

I am not familiar in coding, use Xcode 6.3.2

Here is my code of ViewController.m:

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSString *fullURL = @"http://www.mywebsite.com";
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:fullURL];
    NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [_viewWeb loadRequest:requestObj];
}


- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType {

    // Check if this was a click event and then some other criteria for determining if you want to launch Safari.
    if (navigationType == UIWebViewNavigationTypeLinkClicked
        && [ [ request.URL scheme ] isEqualToString: @"http" ] ) {
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:request.URL];

    // Return false to indicate to the UIWebView to not navigate to the linked target
    return false;
}

// Return true so that the UIWebView loads the link target
return true;
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

please help

Answer (score 0):

Update your method

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType {
```

in something like:

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType {
NSString *requestURL = [[request URL] absoluteString];

    if ([requestURL rangeOfString:@"mydomain.com"].location != NSNotFound) {
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[request URL]];
        return NO;
    }
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: tried, but no luck that it still doesn't work, sorry. The url link still open in the UIWebview.

Comment: Have you changed the string in my example?

Comment: @PennyKo This code should open your website in safari, other addresses on a we view. If you want the opposite replace the "!=" with "=="